# Photoshop Basic JS Implementation

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I set up a very basic page http://neighborhoodpets.wink1733.com with three images to try Photoswipe 4.0.

I am following the "Getting Started" documentation at: http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html

I am getting the following error:  (index):162 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

I am new to JS, so I am just copy/pasting the script.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is referencing to `data-size` attribute in yout `anchor` tag:

```
el.getAttribute('data-size')
```

This means that your HTML code for that anchor tag should look like:

```
<a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
```